# FileLoadException on ScheduleJob method

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net

I have successfully loaded the scheduler of my Quartz.NET windows service and I can see that it is currently running one sample job.
But when I try to add a job to the scheduler (on the line `sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger)` below) I get a `FileLoadException` exception that says:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Quartz, Version=2.2.4.400,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f6b8c98a402cc8a4' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

This is the code I am using to get my scheduler and add the job and a trigger to it:

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "RemoteClient";

// set thread pool info
properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "10";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";

// set remoting expoter
properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true";
properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = "tcp://127.0.0.1:555/QuartzScheduler";

ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();
Console.WriteLine("name: " + sched.SchedulerName);
Console.WriteLine("instance id: " + sched.SchedulerInstanceId);
Console.WriteLine("is started: " + sched.IsStarted);
Console.WriteLine("context : " + sched.Context);
var job = JobBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("MyEmailJob", "JobCategory1")
    .RequestRecovery().Build();
var trigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create() 
        .WithIdentity("MyEmailJob", "JobCategory1") 
        .WithCronSchedule("0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *") 
        .StartAt(DateTime.Now) .WithPriority(1).Build();
var schedule = sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

**App.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.Log4net1211">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %l - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="service-log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
      <!-- uncomment to enable event log appending -->
      <!-- <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" /> -->
    </root>
  </log4net>

  <!-- 
    We use quartz.config for this server, you can always use configuration section if you want to.
    Configuration section has precedence here.  
  -->
  <!--
  <quartz >
  </quartz>
  -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: @CircularReference The inner exception returns null but I get this Fusionlog with it: WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: @CircularReference thank you for you time by the way. You seem to be the only person who could actually solve my Quartz.NET problems.

Comment: @CircularReference maybe I should define the type of job I am building? like var job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()?

Comment: what does your config file look like? Specifically the reference to quartz

Comment: @CircularReference I have nothing about quartz in my app.config. I just get the scheduler in my Main method as above.

Comment: @CircularReference I am sorry, there is a quartz section in my app.config. I will update it in my question.

Comment: @CircularReference updated with app.config now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an assembly mismatch issue, rather than anything to do with quartz.net. It means your app cannot find the exact version of Quartz.dll at runtime. The version in your bin folder is different than the one referenced by your project.

Try removing the reference from your projects and re-adding it. Pick the one that your windows service uses. Clean solution, rebuild.

If you installed Quartz using nuget, you need to uninstall it via nuget first.

Comment: Genius! Thank you. Lesson learned that I should always use the dll that my server is using.